# HAProxy uses 100% CPU

Tags: haproxy

I am using the latest HAProxy on Ubuntu 11.10 and at that moment, I had 3000 connections (according to HAProxy Stats), the configuration is used based on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection). I am not sure if it is normal for HAProxy to consume that much CPU with 3000 connections? Also I am not sure what the red bar (Kernel threads) means to HAProxy

[image]

Comment: not a virtual machine?

Comment: I am using Linode

Comment: CPU usage stats are not accurate within a VM because it will take more or less CPU time based on how busy it or other machines are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I re-install Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and recompile HAProxy

```
make TARGET=linux26 ARCH=x86_64 CPU=native USE_STATIC_PCRE=1
```

Everything works fine, no more high CPU usage

Comment: This page has some more info on the options: http://louwrentius.com/how-to-compile-haproxy-from-source-and-setup-a-basic-configuration.html